# Two div side by side in one container css

Tags: css

I want to have two div side by side in one container: the first is an image (the width is fixed but the code should be applied  for different images with different widths) . The second will take the rest of the container.

```
.conteiner {
   position: relative;
}
.image{
   display: inline-block;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   position: absolute;
   width: auto;
}
.text{
   display: inline-block;
   position: relative;
   max-width: 100%;  
}
```

But the image will be placed over the text.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="text">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullmaco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea consequat.
        </p>
</div>
<div class="image">
    <img width="151" height="97">
</div>
```

In this example, the image had width 151px and 97 px height. But but for other images should not be the same.

Comment: remove the position: absolute from the image

Comment: After seeing img comes after text: can you change this order or is this a requirement?

Comment: What happens when text is higher than image: should it wrap under image like good ole' floating image happens to behave or should it create "columns"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `top: 0;right: 0;position: absolute;` to stop your `.image` from being positioned absolutely so that the text does not overlap it.

alter your width's to match so that `P` doesn't take over the width.

also add `vertical-align:top;` to keep items to the top.

see bellow

```css
.conteiner {
  position: relative;
}
.align {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.text {
  max-width: 50%;
}
.image {
  max-width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text align">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullmaco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea consequat.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="image align">
    <img width="151" height="97">
  </div>
```

This might be a more prudent solution for what you are after.

```css
.conteiner {
     position: relative;
     display:table;
   }
   .align {
     vertical-align: top;
     display: table-cell;
     position: relative;
   }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text align">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullmaco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea consequat.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="image align">
    <img width="151" height="97">
  </div>
```

Comment: the text will take 100% width and the image will be placed after the text.

Comment: Demo added. Float should not be used in conjunction with inline-block;

Comment: "the first is an image (...) The second will take the rest of the container" - Ok, I didn't know we're counting from right side :p

Comment: @AyoubAbid I have updated to show an alternative that might be more what your looking for but it does not use inline-block.

Answer (score 0):

This is achieved by giving the image (or the image container) a `float:left` and the text container a `margin-left`.

Please take a look at this example:

https://jsfiddle.net/k4054xkm/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        <h1>Testtext</h1>
        <p>A bit of Testtext</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
   position: relative;
}
.image{
   float:left;
   width:200px;
}
.text{
   margin-left:220px;
}
```

Please adjust the width and margin-left to your needs.

Comment: the image can have bigger or smaller width. Why should i choose 200px as a width.

Answer (score 0):

You have position absolute on .image this mean that this block not realy takes width and the second block is relative he will take the same place the absolute block takes .image (over or under it). 
you can try to rewrite css like this:

```
.conteiner {
}
.image{    
float:right;
width: auto;
}
.text{
float: right;
max-width: 100%;  
}
```

you can replace float: right to float: left if you start from left side.

Comment: can you make screenshot of the result after you added my css ?